# my nav and div won´t be a side, don´t know what's wrong

Tags: html, css, split

At this link: 
http://thom239u.keaweb.dk/help/mit.html
i have a div called main (black border) and a nav (red border)

i have tried everything, why ain´t they a side

when they are empty they are side by side, 
but when i put something in them they split.. ?
i tried to erase it all and start from beginning again, but wont help.. 
![enter image description here][1]

i'm trying to get i nav a left an a div box where i can change what's in it.

Answer (score 4):

Please add 
`vertical-align: top;` to #main

Answer (score 3):

You should use `float:left;` 
You can add that to the `<Nav>` and `<Div id="main">`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Additionally, under the standard box model, they will not correctly align side by side at lower resolutions if you use width % and have a border/padding. You are using `width:10%` and `width:89%` for each element, I'm assuming you were trying to make them fit and 10%/90% wasn't working.

If you apply [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) to each of the elements, it will take into account the extra width allocated to borders/padding of that element, and allow you to simply state 10% width & 90% width.

Answer (score 1):

You need only vertical-align to `#main`, since `display:inline-block` elements need to be aligned.

```
#main{
    vertical-align:top;
    /* other styles*/
}
```

[whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)